# Firebase Dynamic Link social image not shown, link not clickable in some apps like Instagram

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links, deeplink

I'm experimenting with Firebase Dynamic Links and so far all of it works, but not the part with the social parameters. Whenever I share my link it only has the actual clickable link and a message sent through the `intent` but there's no social title, image or description. I am currently adding my image through `drawable` folder and the image is less than 300kb and at least 300x200. For example when I share my link through `Viber` it only says `Hey, check out my link: <the link here>`

Sharing on `WhatsApp` it does work, the image is shown along with the social title and description, but `Viber` and `Instagram` do not show the social metadata. Also, the link on `Instagram` is not clickable. How do I debug this?

Here's my code:

```
    private fun createShareUri(deepId: String): Uri {
        val builder = Uri.Builder()
        builder.scheme(getString(R.string.config_scheme)) // "http"
                .authority(getString(R.string.config_host)) // "deeplink.xyz"
                .appendPath(getString(R.string.config_path_deep)) // "deep"
                .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM_DEEP, deepId)
        return builder.build()
    }

private fun createDynamicUri(myUri: Uri): Uri {
        val imgUri = getUriToResource(this, R.drawable.mypic)
        val dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                .setLink(myUri)
                .setDynamicLinkDomain(DYNAMIC_LINK_DOMAIN)
                .setAndroidParameters(DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder()
                        .build())
                .setSocialMetaTagParameters(DynamicLink.SocialMetaTagParameters.Builder()
                        .setTitle("Social Meta Title")
                        .setDescription("Social Meta Description")
                        .setImageUrl(imgUri)
                        .build())
                .buildDynamicLink()
        return dynamicLink.uri
    }

private fun shortenLink(linkUri: Uri) {
        FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                .setLongLink(linkUri)
                .buildShortDynamicLink()
                .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        val shortLink = task.result.shortLink
                        val msg = "Hey, check out my link: $shortLink"
                        val sendIntent = Intent()
                        sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, msg)
                        sendIntent.type = "text/plain"
                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share via"))
                    } else {
                        Timber.e(task.exception)
                    }
                }
    }

private fun share(id: String) {
        val myUri = createShareUri(id)
        Timber.d("Shared Link: $myUri")

        val dynamicLinkUri = createDynamicUri(myUri)
        Timber.d("Dynamic Link: $dynamicLinkUri")

        shortenLink(dynamicLinkUri)
    }
```

**Edit:** here's my dynamic link: `https://deeplinktest.page.link?sd=Social%20Meta%20Description&si=android.resource%3A%2F%2Fcom.example.deeplinktest.deeplinks%2Fdrawable%2Fmypic&st=Social%20Meta%20Title&apn=com.example.deeplinktest.deeplinks&link=https%3A%2F%2Fdeeplink.xyz%2Fdeep%3FdeepId%3D2`

Comment: share your generated dynamic link

Comment: @RutvikBhatt I've added it now.

Comment: You are setting Image URL from the drawable resource that is not available for public (Use image link that is available on the Internet) and checks if you add your SHA key to firebase console.

Comment: @RutvikBhatt I've checked my SHA key and it is the correct one. I've also tried to use a link for an image available on the internet, but I still get the same result.

Comment: @RutvikBhatt Did you find a solution. My dynamic link on instagram is not clickable..

Comment: @niranjankurambhatti Is your link clickable in other platforms like WhatsApp or Facebook or Text Message?

Comment: @RutvikBhatt yes on whatsapp it is clickable.I noticed that instagram checks if the link has .com in it if not it does not detect it.